# How do you add 2 outlines/borders inside an image

Tags: css

How do you create two outlines or borders using css like the demo pic below?

[image]

I can create one outline as per the code here: [JSFIDDLE CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/k3rcyquo/)

**CSS:**

```
img {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -9px;
}
```

Comment: @ guy who edited question..your edit is totally waste ot time as op already gave a link to jsfiddle which is quite better then this change which you did..please don't do this type of editing for few points..thanx

Comment: @Leothelion sorry. How to rollback?

Comment: well its ok for now but please be careful next time..thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 3%;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}
.wrapper__img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="wrapper__img" src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/2007-hybrid-car-pictures-3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I found this to be the best so far. I used px units for the top, right, left etc properties instead of percentages and it seems to work nicely when using different sized images. Thank you :)

Comment: You can do it with a single pseudo but good enough for an upvote anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/x7c4a73m/

Comment: Yep, it can be done with only one element. You use calc(100% - x) for equal paddings. Pretty.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```css
img {
    outline: 4px double #fff;
    outline-offset: -12px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/2007-hybrid-car-pictures-3.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: The drawback with using double is the space between the two lines/boxes cannot be controlled.

Comment: This works, however wonder if there is a better solution that lets you control the distance between the 2 lines as per the comment above?

Comment: Also IE does not support ``outline-offset``.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [IE doesn't support outline offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset#Browser_Compatibility). You'd be better off using the image as your background in CSS and using some inner divs for the borders.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pad {
  padding: 5px;
}
.image {
  background: url('http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/2007-hybrid-car-pictures-3.jpg') no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 266px;
}
.inner-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="image pad">
  <div class="inner-border pad">
    <div class="inner-border"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well this is nice try but it is not responsive and if image width will change it will disturbed.. :(

Comment: Responsiveness is not relevant to the original question.

Comment: yes but then its not perfect solution..thats why i said nice try. Please don't take my words in other way but i just wanted to notify you so may be there will be better solution..sorry